# Can I disable CUDA temporarily in PyTorch?

Tags: linux, cuda, pytorch

I am trying to determine if the expense of a GPU is worth it for a particular task. I currently have PyTorch code running on a GPU enabled machine. I would love to be able to disable the GPU for a single run to do a direct comparison (everything else equal) of the benefits of the GPU to the task.

Is there anyway to tell PyTorch to ignore the GPU or to tell the OS to pretend that it doesn't have one? I'm running this on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, using python 3.8.5 and torch 1.7.1.

UPDATE: This is code I inherited so I cannot speak to its efficiency but there are many places in the code where we have things like ...

```
tensors = get_tensors()
if torch.cuda.device_count() >= 1:
    tensers = tensors.cuda()
```

... and for the model its ...

```
num_cuda = torch.cuda.device_count()
model = get_model()
if num_cuda == 1:
    model = model.cuda()
elif num_cuda > 1:
    model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)
```

Comment: `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""` before your python shell starts, or `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = ''`  before `import torch`

Comment: To add to robert's answer, you should also just be able to cast your model to cpu by calling `model.cpu()` rather than `model.cuda()`.

Comment: Cheers both of you! I updated my answer to explain why I went with Robert's reply. Thank you, that worked! If you make an answer I can accept it. And thanks @jhso too.

Comment: Oh, also I found it necessary. :) 41 seconds vs. 5 minutes and 49 seconds.